# Convert string minutes to hours

Tags: asp.net

I will receive a string of minutes and I would like to convert that into the total amount of time spent.

if it is 90 minutes I would want to convert it to 1 hour and 30 minutes.

if it was 150 minutes I would want it to convert to 2 hours and 30 minutes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DataTable data = GeneralFunctions.GetData( query );
object sumObject;
sumObject = data.Compute( "Sum(Minutes_Spent)", "" );
if ( reportType == 1 )
{
    RepeaterPCBillable.DataSource = data;
    RepeaterPCBillable.DataBind();
    LabelPCBillable.Text = sumObject.ToString();
}
else
```

I'm not sure if there is some built in time function that will produce the results i need or if i will need to do some type of division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built in.

You will need to write your own parsing routines for your string.

Example in C#:

```
// assumes input is valid for integer parsing
int totalMinutes = int.Parse(inputString);
int hours = totalMinuts / 60;
int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
```

Comment: ive always having trouble understanding the # vs .0 in formatting... no matter how many article i read...:(

Comment: Does this have any advantage over the suggested TimeSpan others have suggested?

Comment: to read the existsing is fine but when im trying to do something of my own - i always fail... foe example : `123456.ToString(",00")` meaning : i want every 2 digits - a comma like this : `12,34,56` ( not related to math - but i want it like that )

Comment: @JamesWilson - Simple to understand. You can also not get over 23 hours with `TimeSpan` (it start rolling over to days).

Comment: Ahh, in that case I will have to go this route as I could go over 24 hours.  And it is billed by hours.  Thank you!

Comment: @JamesWilson - Just to be clear, with `TimeSpan` you can always do `ts.TotalDays * 24` and add `ts.Hours` and `ts.Minutes` to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TimeSpan.FromMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx), and then retrieve hours and minutes from it.

```
var span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(inputString));
var hours = span.Hours;
var minutes = span.Minutes;
```

Comment: @Oded Wouldn't C# automatically convert my `int` to `double`?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in, but it's not hard to do. Let's do this step-by-step. This is our example input:

```
var input = "130 minutes";
```

Now we use a regular expression to extract the number in front of `minutes`:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(\d+) minutes$");
if (!match.Success)
    throw new Exception("Invalid input format");
```

Then, we convert the string with the minutes into an integer:

```
var minutes = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);    // now contains 130
```

Next, we split hours and minutes, using integer division and modulo operation:

```
var hours = minutes / 60;
minutes = minutes % 60;
```

And, lastly, we can format the result into a string again:

```
var result = String.Format("{0} hours and {1} minutes", hours, minutes);  // 2 hours and 10 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a general algorithm:

```
int hours=string_minutes/60;
int minutes=string_minutes%60;
```

Basically the first operation gives you Quotient and then the second one gives you the Remainder/

Comment: By the way, do convert the string_minutes to Int first